# Select element on DOM doesn't update the table on page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

i'm trying to select the 4 option on the select argument, by using jquery and after choose the option all the page doesn't update the result.

This is for a puppeteer code to scrape all the cnaes on IBGE page.

[IBGE CNAE](https://cnae.ibge.gov.br/?view=classe&tipo=cnae&versao=10&classe=03221)
It only show the first ten elements even after choosing the option all("todos") with jquery instead of all the 35.

```
document.getElementsByName("tbResult_length")[0].selectedIndex = 4
```

Comment: Check all event listeners from this element. selectedIndex will trigger 'onchange', but maybe other code triggering your goal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the doc about what a Good Stack Overflow question should contain [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I already tried that. But in  the events that happened on this element that isn't any kind of change when i make the request.